# Vapor: How to coordinate multiple requests until one central one is done

Tags: swift, vapor

I have a middleware which fetches a token if there is no one to be found in Redis.

```swift
struct TokenMiddleware: Middleware, TokenAccessor {

  func respond(to request: Request, chainingTo next: Responder) throws -> Future<Response> {
    guard let _ = request.http.headers.firstValue(name: HTTPHeaderName("Client-ID")) else {
      throw Abort(.badRequest, reason: "missing 'Client-ID' in header")
    }
    guard request.clientID.isEmpty == false else {
      throw Abort(.badRequest, reason: "'Client-ID' in header is empty")
    }
    guard let _ = request.http.headers.firstValue(name: HTTPHeaderName("Client-Secret")) else {
      throw Abort(.badRequest, reason: "missing 'Client-Secret' in header")
    }
    /// getToken fetches a new Token and stores it in Redis for the controller to use
    return try self.getToken(request: request).flatMap(to: Response.self) { token in
      return try next.respond(to: request)
    }

  }

}

extension TokenMiddleware: Service {}
```

But this causes multiple processes fetching new tokens on their own and therefore a race condition.

How can I handle this in vapor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem now, thanks to Soroush from http://khanlou.com/2017/09/dispatch-on-the-server/ who hinted me into the right direction. More infos on the DispatchQueues can be found in an excellent article from https://www.raywenderlich.com/5370-grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-for-swift-4-part-1-2

So:

In both iOS and Vapor on the Server we can create a `DispatchQueue`. In my case I am using a concurrent one that, in the critical part where token reading, fetching (if needed) and token writing happens, I use a barrier.

The barrier lets only one in and thus in this part everything is executed like a serial queue.

Hope this helps anybody that might come across the same issue

```swift
import Vapor

protocol TokenAccessor: RedisAccessor {
}


extension TokenAccessor {

  ///   Main convenience function that handles expiry, refetching etc
  ///
  /// - Check if token was saved before
  /// - We store the token in redis
  /// - We use redis TTL feature to handle token expiry
  ///
  func getToken(request: Request) throws -> Future<Token> {
    print(":getToken(request:)")
    let promise = request.eventLoop.newPromise(Token.self)
    return request.withNewConnection(to: .redis) { redis in
      let concurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.queuename.gettoken",
                                          attributes: .concurrent)
      /// Making the concurrent queue serial because only one is allowed to fetch a new token at a time
      concurrentQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
        let _ = redis.get(request.clientIdLastDigits, as: String.self).map(to: Void.self) { tokenOpt in
          guard let accessToken = tokenOpt else {
            try self.fetchNewToken(forRequest: request).do { newToken in
              print("fetched a new token")
              promise.succeed(result: newToken)
              }.catch { error in
                print("failed fetching a new token")
                promise.fail(error: error)
            }
            return
          }
          print("got a valid token from redis")
          let token = Token(client: request.clientIdLastDigits, token: accessToken, expiresIn: Date())
          // return request.future(token)
          promise.succeed(result: token)
        }
      }
      return promise.futureResult
    }
  }
...
```

This is triggered in front of my methods via a middleware (so I don't need to think about it)

```swift
import Vapor

struct TokenMiddleware: Middleware, TokenAccessor {

  func respond(to request: Request, chainingTo next: Responder) throws -> Future<Response> {
    guard let _ = request.http.headers.firstValue(name: HTTPHeaderName("Client-ID")) else {
      throw Abort(.badRequest, reason: "missing 'Client-ID' in header")
    }
    guard request.clientID.isEmpty == false else {
      throw Abort(.badRequest, reason: "'Client-ID' in header is empty")
    }
    guard let _ = request.http.headers.firstValue(name: HTTPHeaderName("Client-Secret")) else {
      throw Abort(.badRequest, reason: "missing 'Client-Secret' in header")
    }
    return try self.getToken(request: request).flatMap(to: Response.self) { token in
      return try next.respond(to: request)
    }

  }

}

extension TokenMiddleware: Service {}
```